# How to prevent the Title column from automatically getting the initial value of the Name column?

Tags: document-library

How to prevent the Title column from automatically getting the initial value of the Name column?

When I upload a new document in my doc library, I see the column's name and title has the same value, the name of the document. Can I prevent that the title column gets this value automatically?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent that, but you can change the Title once the document is uploaded and you see the document metadata form?

Comment: no, I do not want for each new document the clear the title